# Oracle: one query to output different where condition result

Tags: oracle

I've got the following query which output plots 3 rows and 3 columns.
For each "Owner" I want to extract on the same line the "PDF" in common and the "PDF" that doesn't exist on the second table.

Do you know other elegant and faster way to show in the same query output the result of different where conditions?

```
WITH temp
     AS (SELECT T.OWNER,
                (SELECT FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE
                   FROM DUAL
                  WHERE EXISTS
                           (SELECT 1
                              FROM NETATEMP.BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO p
                             WHERE p.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE = t.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE))
                   "Pdf in comune",
                (SELECT FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE
                   FROM DUAL
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                           (SELECT 1
                              FROM NETATEMP.BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO p
                             WHERE p.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE = t.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE))
                   "Pdf NON in comune"
           FROM NETATEMP.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF t)
  SELECT owner, COUNT (DISTINCT "Pdf in comune") "Pdf in comune", COUNT (DISTINCT "Pdf NON in comune") "Pdf NON in comune"
    FROM temp
GROUP BY OWNER
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an external join, I hoped I understood your need:

```
select OWNER, sum(common) "Pdf in comune", count(*) - sum(common) "Pdf NON in comune"
from
(
  select t.OWNER, p.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE,
         decode(t.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE, null, 0, 1) common
  from NETATEMP.TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF t,
       NETATEMP.BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO p
  where p.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE (+) = t.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE
)
group by OWNER
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your existing query, you're trying to show the following:

- Column 1: Owner
- Column 2: **1** if the `TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE` value exists in the BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO table or **0** if it doesn't exist
- Column 3: the opposite of column 2

You can do this a lot more efficiently with an outer join:

```
SELECT
  T.OWNER,
  MAX(CASE
     WHEN P.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE IS NOT NULL THEN 1
     ELSE 0 END) AS "Pdf in comune",
  MAX(CASE
     WHEN P.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE IS NULL THEN 1
     ELSE 0 END) AS "Pdf NON in comune"
FROM TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF T
LEFT JOIN BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO P
     ON T.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE = P.FLH_PUNTO_EROGAZIONE
GROUP BY T.OWNER
```

When you left join, any `TMP_BACKLOG_NOBILLING2013_UFF` row that doesn't have a match in `BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO` will have `NULL` values for the `BACKLOG_NOBILL_STORICO` columns. The `CASE` and `MAX` use this to get to the `1` or `0`.

Comment: No, the query should count the number of row which matches and the number of row which doesn't. Shouldn't I use a left outer join?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing table structures (or sample data or expected output), but if you need to count then changing the two `MAX` functions above to `COUNT` might do the trick. Also note: `LEFT JOIN` is the same thing as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - the `OUTER` keyword is optional.